# How to browse through a SortedMap?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `SortedMap<String, SortedMap<String, Integer>>`. where each string is a question with possible answers and points attached.

How can I use this `Map` to print questions (first one, second one, ...) by their positions like `sampleArray[0]`?

Comment: What is the purpose of using a `Map` for this?  Why not just use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: You want your questions sorted lexicographically?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's not in my power. That's what I get and that's what I have to use.

Comment: You can use the entrySet method, to get the set of entries, in ascending key order. Is that what you want ?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#entrySet()

Comment: @Saphire Did you read the javadoc of `SortedMap` ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can iterate through your map is:

```
for (String aQuestion : myMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(aQuestion)); //Prints each question.  
    System.out.println(myMap.get(aQuestion)); //Prints each answer using the same for loop
}
```

Alternatively to get the answers you can do:

```
myMap.values();
```

This gets a Collection with all the values, or answers in your case.  Collection has a method toArray() which will return an ordinary array for easy iteration.  But you can also use ArrayList's addAll(Collection c) method to make an arraylist too.

```
List<String> myAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
myAnswers.addAll(myMap.values());
```

Comment: Can I select an item from the keySet() by its position?

Comment: keySet() returns a Set. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html It's a list with only unique values.  You can call Set's toArray() method to get an ordinary array out of it though to iterate through in a more familiar fashion.

Comment: And how do I iterate through all possible answers?

Comment: I'll add it in my answer.

Comment: Can I get `myMap` as a variable where just one question at `0` is in?

Comment: As in, your SortedMap has only one question in it?  And you just want to get a single reference to that one question?

Comment: My original SortedMap has a lot of questions. But I want to print one question and its answers one by one. Without a loop.

Comment: As the key, you need to have the questions stored somewhere where you can use their value.  You can't do it by index like an ArrayList.  You need to have the key to look up whether you use a loop to get it, or have it by other means.  Let me know if that helps!

Comment: I have the question in `String key = set.toArray()[0];` but where do I go from there to get the questions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54391/discussion-between-julian-cleary-and-saphire).

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (Entry<String, SortedMap<String, Integer>> q : test.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Question=" + q.getKey());
        for (Entry<String, Integer> a : q.getValue().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Answer: " + a.getKey() + " for points " + a.getValue());

        }
    }
```

or if you're usin java8

```
    test.entrySet().stream().forEach((q) -> {
        System.out.println("Question=" + q.getKey());
        q.getValue().entrySet().stream().forEach((a) -> {
            System.out.println("Answer: " + a.getKey() + " for points " + a.getValue());
        });
    });
```

Btw, when you describing types, use interfaces/abstract classes if possible for example

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> test;
```

not

```
SortedMap<String, SortedMap<String, Integer>> test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like with usual map, you can iterate over key set:

```
SortedMap<String, SortedMap<String, Integer>> questions;

//some processing

for (String question : questions.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(question);
}
```